# Is Heroku Release Phase one-off dyno exposed to the public network?

Tags: heroku, continuous-integration, release

I want to run GhostInspector (or similar) as part of CI/CD. The tests would execute as part of the release phase for staging, then if successful, production will be deployed. Does this work? Is the dyno publicly accessible with the usual staging url?

Answer (score 1):

short answer: one-off dynos are not publicly accessible to the internet.

For your use-case the way on heroku would be pipelines:

- deploy your app to a testing-stage app
- run ghost-inspector there
- promote to production/staging afterwards

(you can control all this via easy cli or api-requests)

alternative: find a tool that runs headless (inside the dynos) or can be called from the dynos (Browserstack can be used like this in a CI/CD/Pipeline)